# How do I map over an exported array in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of strings stored in a .jsx file and exported like this:

Streamers.jsx:

```
const channels = ["freecodecamp","test_channel","dyrus", "uberdanger", 
"boxbox"];

module.exports = {channels};
```

App.jsx:

```
import channels from "../../variables/streamers.jsx";
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <div className="card-container">
          {
            channels.map((channel, index) => {
            return (
              <Twitch key={index} streamer={channel} />
            );
            })
          }
     
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This in turn gives me a typerror saying `variables_streamers_jsx___default.a.map is not a function`.
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EJvk.png)

When I define the array locally in the App.jsx file it works fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `import { channels } from "../../variables/streamers.jsx";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove the object part form the `exports`. You have wrapped the `channels` in an object. Either remove the object part or use `channels.channels`

```
module.exports = channels;
```

or

```
channels.channels.map((channel, index) => {
   return (<Twitch key={index} streamer={channel} />);
})
```

Comment: Oh yes that was the problem. I didn't realized I used the curly braces to export the array. Thanks!